# Scroll page to the table with result using Rails ransack params

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ransack

I have a page with sorting(ransack gem) and pagination, at the top of the page there is general information, at the bottom table with 10 items per page. If the user clicks on pagination or sorting buttons I would like to automatically scroll to the table skipping the top area.

Using `URLSearchParams` i could track clicks on pagination buttons, but when the user clicks on one of the sorting buttons **ransack** added something like `%5Bs%5D=description+asc` and I can't track it using `URLSearchParams`.

```js
const url = `http://localhost:3000/articles`;
const urlWithSorting = `http://localhost:3000/articles?q%5Bs%5D=started_at+desc`;
const urlWithPageAndSorting = `http://localhost:3000/articles?page=1&q%5Bs%5D=started_at+desc`;

const searchParams = new URLSearchParams(urlWithPageAndSorting);

// url 
const hasPageParams = searchParams.has('page'); // false
const hasSortingParams = searchParams.has('s'); // false

// urlWithSorting 
const hasPageParams = searchParams.has('page'); // false
const hasSortingParams = searchParams.has('s'); // false

// urlWithPageAndSorting 
const hasPageParams = searchParams.has('page'); // true
const hasSortingParams = searchParams.has('s'); // false

if (hasPageParams || hasSortingParams) {
 scroll(0, $(".js-article-table").position().top);
}
```

Any ideas on how to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These URLs are just the encoded version of a standard bracketized query:

```
http://localhost:3000/articles?q%5Bs%5D=started_at+desc
http://localhost:3000/articles?q[s]=started_at+desc
```

If you try to print out the URLSearchParams instance, you will get:

```
console.log([...searchParams].toString())
// q[s],started_at desc
```

so you can use

```
searchParams.has('q[s]')
```

Also, be aware that you cannot pass a full URL to the constructor, you have to build a URL before, and use only the search part:

```
searchParams = new URLSearchParams(new URL(urlWithPageAndSorting).search)
```

Comment: great, that was what I missed, thanks for the answer.